# Who decided on the terminology downcasting and upcasting?

Tags: terminology, history, inheritance

As far as I know, the terminology comes from how the **inheritance hierarchy** is traditionally displayed, with the extending types at the bottom, and the parent types at the top.

This is a bit pointless, unless you feel like calling the following *leftcasting* and *rightcasting*.

[image: horizontal inheritance hierarchy]

I am *not looking for opinions* why the terminology is as is, but they are more than welcome as comments. I am looking for references on **who first introduced up and downcasting, and why they decided on that name**.

Comment: My previous answer on [where the term _abstract_ came from](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/47932/15464) might be a nice starting point. [SIMULA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) should be an important reference when looking for the history on inheritance.

Comment: Although they're somewhat self-explanatory, I haven't heard anyone actually *use* these terms.  Have ye a reference?  IOW: "You upcast to an object which can do less, and you downcast to an object which can do more." [citation needed]

Comment: I consider upcasting safer (you go towards a type that's guaranteed to have at least a subset of the members of the starting type), whereas when downcasting you can't be really sure of what you'll find. Safer -> better, so the typical reasoning you use, works. [/opinion]

Comment: I think these terms may eventually be lost to posterity as most other computer science terms like Kilo, Mega, and Gigabytes meaning  2^10, 2^20, 2^30 vs. 10^3, 10^6, 10^9.  The further we go away from the original architecture of computers as binary machines the more we will go away from n-ary trees growing down vs. up as they do in the normal world.  So to me there is no confusion in the meaning of the terms but then again may be it's just me.

Comment: @Task: Concerning actual use of downcast: [msdn uses it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysezk96b.aspx).

Comment: And quite more importantly. Did you [read the article](http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/20719-upcasting-downcasting.html) from where you got the dog / cat image? If not, it supports my previous comment: upcasting is safer, as it can never fail, downcasting on the other hand can. Also I'd add that upcasting gets us at a higher abstraction level (if that makes it easier for you to remember).

Comment: It's not so easy to search for their origins because [upcasting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upcast) and [downcasting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/downcast) have older meanings. But perhaps those meanings influenced the OOP words. But the [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downcasting%2Cupcasting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows big increases around 1980 and 1995. The earliest certain references to *downcast[ing]* I found are from 1992 in C++ literature...

Comment: *Downcasting* references from 1992: Allen I. Holub - *[C + C++: programming with objects in C and C++](http://bit.ly/tKlkmK)*, Raimund K. Ege, Madhu Singh, Bertrand Meyer - *[Technology of object-oriented languages and systems: TOOLS 8 : proceedings of the eighth International Conference, TOOLS Santa Barbara 1992](http://bit.ly/rKnszo)*, Richard Wiener - *[Journal of object-oriented programming, Volume 5](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=32T0TsL4JYGE-wa-7ZSrAQ&id=W3lVAAAAMAAJ&dq="downcast"+"object+oriented"&q=downcasting+OR+downcast+OR+upcast+OR+upcasting)*.

Comment: @Hugo: Cool, I'm continuing my search later today. Yesterday I was following references to Robin Milner's paper from 1978 on [A Theory of Type Polymorphism in Programming](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.67.5276). It gave some interesting results. This paper describes well-typing as "correct type assignments" and type checking as "discover a legal type assignment". Don't know how relevant they are yet. :)

Comment: Hmm, had the phrases been "subcast" and "supercast" to go with "sub-type", etc., I think the words would seem less backward and mentally correlate than "downcast", etc. Think I'll read [Gulliver travels and bet on the little endianders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Etymology).

Answer (score 4):

Basically the `down-` and `up-cast` is the logical continuation of the `subtype` (`subclass` in OOP) and `supertype` (`superclass` respectively), e.g. the classical representation of the derived type to be located below the original type -- `sub`type.

If we search for the term `subtyping` we find the following ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism)):

> The notion of subtyping in programming languages dates back to the
>   1960s; it was introduced in Simula derivatives. The first formal
>   treatments of subtyping were given by John C. Reynolds in 1980 who
>   used category theory to formalize implicit conversions, and Luca
>   Cardelli (1985).

So, as many other things, it originated in something vaguely called here as "Simula derivatives" (probably early OOP languages). Simula, however, already has the notion of [subclass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula), but does not feature all the properties of OOP.

Comment: As stated in my question: _"the terminology comes from how the inheritance hierarchy is traditionally displayed"_. This doesn't explain the reason why "sub" and "super" should be displayed as "up" and "down". I already added SIMULA as a comment.

Comment: Hmm... So, you don't see connection between "sub" and "down"? What about subtitles, Subzero, subliminal and other common English words?

Comment: P.s.: In SIMULA [the concept of inheritance was originally called, "concatenation", and later "prefixing"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/47932/15464). I don't recall reading about subtyping or supertyping when reading the SIMULA documentation. I believe this is a term which only emerged later.

Comment: Just did some rereading of the [SIMULA documentation](http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/Simula-CommonBaseLanguage.pdf). Subclass is indeed used, but not subtype. By rereading your answer I now know what you meant. :) Would still prefer an actual reference, but I see how you go from "sub" to lower.

Comment: [Section 3.2.5](http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/Simula-CommonBaseLanguage.pdf): _"An object reference is said to be "subordinate" to a second object reference if the qualification of the former is a subclass of the class which qualified the latter. A proper procedure is said to be of "type universal". Any type is subordinate to the universal type."_

Comment: @StevenJeuris: it's actually not that clear cut; a subclass typically have more features than the parent class; in an alternate world, we may be using the term "promote" or "demote"  for "downcasting" and "upcasting" respectively, if we think that a supertype is a subordinate of the subclass because a subclass is more powerful/has more features than the superclass. IMO the real reason why these terms are used are mostly historical accidents.

Comment: @LieRyan: That is more or less [the reasoning I was following as well](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/downcasting-whats-up-with-that/), which made me write this question. An older edit of the post contains this reasoning as well, but I had to remove it as some people were calling it a rant.

Comment: Well, this happens when you (in zhe general sense) does not actually read the cited  primary literature: Reynolds (1985) uses "subtype/subsort" exectly the opposite way as "subclass" in modern OOP lingo, he considers `integer` to be a subtype of `real` (see page 217). For him sub means "you have a narrower interface / you can do pess operations on it". So would up/downcast originate from his usage its meanings would be exactly flipped.

Answer (score 4):

The oldest reference I've found yet is from Sep 1990, in [a Usenet post](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.g++.bug/msg/0f9930a029cf2657?dmode=source).

The library referenced there is the NIHCL ([available from the Software Preservation Group](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/library/index.html#NIHCL)), which contains this code (`MI` is "multiple inheritance"):

```
#ifdef MI

#define DECLARE_CASTDOWN(classname) \
    static classname& castdown(Object& p) \
        { return *(classname*)(&p ? p._safe_castdown(*desc()) : 0); } \
    static const classname& castdown(const Object& p) \
        { return *(const classname*)(&p ? p._safe_castdown(*desc()) : 0); } \
    static classname* castdown(Object* p) \
        { return (classname*)(p ? p->_safe_castdown(*desc()) : 0); } \
    static const classname* castdown(const Object* p) \
        { return (const classname*)(p ? p->_safe_castdown(*desc()) : 0); } \

#else

#define DECLARE_CASTDOWN(classname) \
    static classname& castdown(Object& p)           { return (classname&)p; } \
    static const classname& castdown(const Object& p)   { return (const classname&)p; } \
    static classname* castdown(Object* p)           { return (classname*)p; } \
    static const classname* castdown(const Object* p)   { return (const classname*)p; } \

#endif
```

The book that this code was included with ([*Data Abstraction and Object-Oriented Programming in C++*](http://books.google.co.nz/books?ei=S_kUT-rVEpCKmQXHrYXBAw&id=H5sZAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22Data+abstraction+and+object-oriented+programming+in+C%2B%2B%22+cast+down&q=%22castdown%22#search_anchor)) also uses the term "castdown".

The term "castdown" also [seems to predate "downcast"](http://groups.google.com/groups/search?safe=off&q=%22castdown%22&btnG=Search&as_mind=1&as_minm=1&as_miny=1981&as_maxd=31&as_maxm=12&as_maxy=1990&as_drrb=b&sitesearch=), at least on Usenet.